# regex - match string between two strings

Tags: php, regex

I want:

```
Adress Here
```

from

```
<span class="spm spm_detail_road_v2">Address</span>
                            Address Here
                        </a>
                    </p>

            </dd>
```

I tried using

```
Address[\s\S]*(?=/a)
```

but this captures to infinity...

How can I do regex for such task?

Comment: Dont use regex for this.. DOM parser will be easier..

Comment: You have an invalid HTML, but even in this situation there are better tools than regex for this kind of task. Please provide the language/environment you are working in.

Comment: Regex in what language? @stribizhev: HTML can be valid, it seems like just a part of `dd`.

Comment: is it a complete HTML file?

Comment: @panther: I meant incomplete.

Comment: I am doing this in PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find everything between `</span>` and `</a>`. In PHP it's:

```
preg_match('~</span>\s+(.*)\s+</a>~', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```